# Athena - Json/array value column filling other columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

`updated` and `created` are `Date` columns but Athena is reading them from the array:

[image: JSON]

Comment: Please Edit your question and include the DDL (`CREATE TABLE` command) for this table. You can obtain it by right-clicking the dots next to the table name. Did you define this table manually, or via AWS Glue?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I used AWS crawler to add the table from s3 to Athena. And ran a select query on the table and the result came in distorted like the above screenshot I shared.

Comment: In Amazon Athena, please click the 3-dots next to the table name and click **Generate table DDL**. Please paste that information into your Question. Also, please show us some sample rows from the data file.